# Matlab league of legends...well actually just legends

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have the following plot.

[image: http://imgur.com/jDXYGqg]

I would like to point out all kinds of things in this plot, how i treated the data, etc -

i've got modelname:
modelname={modelA modelB modelC}
and modelsource:
modelsource={home work literature}
and then i do my calculations and process the data differently:
centering={mean standaridization normalizing}

how can i make a plot that accesses those three strings, like legend(modelsource for all three lines, modelsource for three lines, centering for three lines) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add several legends to a plot by copying each of them after its call using `new_handle = copyobj(hlegend1,hfigure)`. This way, legends will not be overwritten.

This plot

[image]

is produced by

```
%declare figure
hfigure = figure('Color', [0.8 0.8 0.8]);

%plot 2 lines (red and blue)
hplot1 = plot(1:10,'w', 'LineWidth',15);
hold on;
hplot2 = plot(10:-1:1,'w', 'LineWidth',15);
set(gca, 'Color','b');

%plot legends
hlegend1 = legend(hplot1, '   I choose  ', 'Location','NorthWestOutside'); 
set(hlegend1, 'Color','w');
new_handle = copyobj(hlegend1,hfigure);       
hlegend2 = legend(hplot2, '   Scotland  ', 'Location','NorthEastOutside','Color','w');    
set(hlegend2, 'Color','w');
```

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. one question though: if you have string information which you want to use modularly to assemble a legend, how do you call it in a legend?

lets say you have a b c...and so on (lets say more than 50 entries like that) and then you want to call number 12, 23 and 46 for display. since it is modular, you cannot just write templates for those numbers, sometimes its more of them, sometimes less. How does that work?

Comment: You may want to read the answer by Steve Lord here: http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/240308 . `legend(h([2 4]), 'green', 'magenta')`

Comment: thank you both, so far ive been still working with my old code, mostly because one aspect was not yet answered (or i missed it): ive got over 50 legend names, ans therefore over 50 colors (i take random colors). because it was nto the most pressing thing to do i didnt care too much but actually i would like to refer to the legends L={a b c d ...etc until z} M={model1 model2} in this fashion: legend([L] [M]). the point is the length always changes of both things to be visualized. do you have a quick fix for that one?